# cudatoolkit 11.7 installing failed through conda

Tags: pytorch, cuda, conda

I tried to install cudatoolkit 11.7 using command "conda install cudatoolkit=11.7", but it failed. however, the website https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/ shows 11.7 is avaliable. how can I do to solve it?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify the channel, i.e.

```
conda install cudatoolkit=11.7 -c nvidia
```

If you're not sure, you can always use `conda search` to check if it is available in a given channel.