# Detectron2: How to start a project?

Tags: python, detectron

Now I have a dataset which has been labeled in COCO format, what shall I do after I downloaded the code of Detectron2 from github?

I've got torch and torchvision now, and it seems that I need to write a .py file, then what should I include in this file? Too much documents that I can't tell which one to follow and how to follow
(btw python version 3.8.1, torch 2.0.0, vision 0.15.1, cuda 11.8, didnot install cudatoolkit cuz I don't know which one to choose

Comment: Have you tried steps from https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/blob/main/INSTALL.md 
To choose the correct version of cudatoolkit for Detectron2, match it with your CUDA version. Since you have CUDA 11.8, install the corresponding cudatoolkit version for compatibility. You can install it via conda using: `conda install cudatoolkit=11.8` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/74910103/6901693